# Import mysql file with c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using this method to import a mysql file:

```
     var process = Process.Start(
            new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = sqlPath,
                Arguments =
                    String.Format(
                        "-C -B --host={0} --user={1} --password={2} --database={3} -e \"\\.                  {4}\"",
                        server, user, password, database, filename),
                ErrorDialog = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
            }
            );

        process.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Data);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Data);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();

        return process.ExitCode;
```

But, the process ends before all modifications from sql file are definetely apply (for example insert a lot of rows). I want to wait until all rows are inserted in the database.

Thanks in advance
Javier

Comment: What is the value of the variable `sqlPath`?

Comment: Have you tried it without StandardInput.Close?

Comment: Hi, sqlPath is "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe". Yes Andy Jones, I tried but it doesn't works.